# how to strategically load firebase data? (android)

Tags: android, performance, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]I want to list 5 of the most subscribed users of my Database into a Recyclerview. But how can I do that, whithout looking at the whole database, but rather sort it by subscriber ammount before hand, as so I can load the 5 users much quicker?

Comment: How about you store 5 of the most subscribed users ?

Comment: That would obviously not work because the database always changes

Comment: Yes that’s what I said add an attribute like number of subscribers and you keep it sorted . That kind of thing

Comment: but how? thats the question. I already have such an attribute, but when i want to call for a list of the 5 most subscribed accounts, it will look at the whole database, because it doesn't know who the 5 most subscirbed accounts are. My question is, how can i instantly sort the database accordingly (in this case # subscribers) when a object (# subscribers) is changed? I'm doing this for the means of performance only.

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: i added a representation of my question

Answer (score 0):

```
Query myTopUsersQuery = databaseReference.child("user").orderByChild("followers").limitToFirst(5);
```